# VCTCXO control voltage circuit recommendations?

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscillator, calibration

I'm building a frequency calibration rig. Right now, I've got a fixed TCXO and it has an uncalibrated drift versus GPS of around 0.185 ppm ±50 ppb. I'm prepared to simply subtract 0.2 ppm from the observed measurement either in the firmware or by hand/eye and call it a day.

But academically, I've considered what I would do if I required the ability to tune out the drift. My trepidation is that the control voltage must be exceedingly stable, possibly in the face of changing environmental conditions. Just sticking a multi-turn pot between Vcc and ground doesn't seem like the best answer... does it?

Connor Winfield has [an application note](http://www.conwin.com/pdfs/AN2093.pdf) with a schematic for supplying the control voltage, but their source is an SPI D/A converter. I'd want to make it a manual adjustment - the multi-turn pot. But is it just as simple as replacing their D/A converter with that pot? If so, then what am I getting out of the precision OP amp immediately following it?

Comment: Yes, just use the pot already. The opamp buffers the control voltage, driving the VCXO with a low-impedance source (relative to the bare pot). You need a precision opamp so that it doesn't introduce errors of its own.

Comment: Just go *atomic timing* already. :)

Comment: @DaveTweed Ok, the case for the buffer is logical to me, except that the VCxCXO I'm looking at claims an input impedance of 100k for its control voltage pin. If I use a 20k pot, is it still advisable to use the buffer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I heard back from Connor Winfield. They confirmed that the purpose of the OP amp is to reduce any potential loading on the source - in their case a D/A converter. However, the input impedance on the control pin is 100k and in my case I'm using a 20k 20 turn pot, so they said I could probably do without it, and I concur.

I have decided to hedge my bet. I'm leaving a footprint for the amp and its related components on the board, but I'm bridging the input to the output with a (normally closed) solder jumper. If it turns out that the pot by itself doesn't work well enough, I can cut the shorting trace and populate the amp.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a good TCXO, why not do the last step, and sync it with GPS?

With a simple controller you can measure the number of TXCO cycles per 1pps pulse of a simple GPS receiver, and use the processor's PWM output to feed the control input. After a long period of operation, you could then store the PWM value in internal EEPROM, if you need/want to disconnect the GPS receiver. You could even maintain ageing characteristics.

A small PIC controller can have 10bit resolution in the PWM!

Comment: -1. That's effectively what I am doing. The question is more about what I would do if I didn't want to do it that way.

Comment: Your original mail does not mention any *automatic* feedback from the GPS, which is what *I* was proposing. And my reply proposes a solution for the voltage adjustment using a PWM. So I would say that this is quite a valid answer. Maybe you didn't read it completely?

Comment: I did say that I was going to subtract the drift from GPS in firmware. And I stand by the -1 because you engaged in a re-architecting exercise instead of answering the question at hand, which is how to perform analog trimming of VCxCXOs. #petpeeve